# Passing a function without nesting

Tags: python

I have a main function that creates a random list and displays different messages stating the different elements and indexes in the list. I want to create a second function that takes the list from the first function and slices it to only the middle 6 numbers.
This is the code I used:

```
import random
def main():
    list1 = []
    for count in range (12):
        number = random.randint(50,100)
        list1.append(number)
    for item in list1:
        item = 12
    print('Here is a list of random integers...\n',list1)
    print('The 4th element in the list is',list1[3])
    print('The element at index 9 is',list1[9])
    print('The smallest element in the list is', min(list1))

    
main()
```

This is the second function I started trying to work on:

```
def change_list(list1):
    change = list1[3:8]
    print(change)

    
change_list(list1)
```

Comment: I do not understand your question. What is the problem?

Comment: As an aside, please use the generic [python] tag for *all* python related questions, you can use a version-specific tag in addition if you want

Comment: OP literally said "I want to create a second function that takes the list from the first function and slices it to only the middle 6 numbers." and provided code that does that for a specific list - how is the problem not clear?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably more along the lines of what you're after:

```
import random


def random_numbers(n, a, b):
    return [random.randint(a, b) for _ in range(n)]


def middle(xs, n):
    distance = n // 2
    remainder = n % 2
    half_size = len(xs) // 2
    return xs[half_size - distance:half_size + remainder + distance]


def main():
    list1 = random_numbers(12, 50, 100)

    print('Here is a list of random integers...\n', list1)
    print('The 4th element in the list is', list1[3])
    print('The element at index 9 is', list1[9])
    print('The smallest element in the list is', min(list1))

    print('The middle 6 elements are:', middle(list1, 6))

main()
```

A few notes:

- the `main()` function just calls the other functions that do some work and prints some messages; anything reusable is its own function. A common mistake for beginning Python programmers is to confuse what `print` does with the use of a `return` statement. You typically want your function to do work and return a result, and print where it's appropriate. What if you want a random list for another purpose, without the printing?
- the list comprehension in `random_numbers` is a more concise and very common way of creating a list in Python.
- the `middle` function does what you need, and expects a list and a number of elements you want from the middle.

Output:

```
Here is a list of random integers...
 [50, 58, 59, 80, 72, 85, 69, 55, 96, 51, 84, 83]
The 4th element in the list is 80
The element at index 9 is 51
The smallest element in the list is 50
The middle 6 elements are: [80, 72, 85, 69, 55, 96]
```

Note that another common confusion with new programmers is that they use global variables (like your `list1`) to pass values between function calls, instead of using parameters like in my example.

Keep in mind that calling `middle(xs, n)` with `middle(list1, 6)` means that, while running the function itself, `xs` will refer to the same list as `list1` and `n` will have the value `6`. `xs` and `list1` don't have to have the same name to be able to refer to the same list. And this way, you can use `middle()` to get the middle of *any* list, instead of just the middle of `list1`.

Answer (score 0):

First find the len of the list using `len`. After that the middle which is the half of the list length. Return 3 elements to the left and 3 to the right of it.

```
def change_list(list1):
    middle = len(list1) // 2
    change = list1[middle-3:middle+3]
    return change
```

**Note**: this function does not check if length of list1 is bigger or equal to 6

Comment: I used 'return', however, it still doesn't go back to the main function?

Comment: You are calling change_list after main, so it's normal not to return to it. You need to call it inside main, after getting your first list.